# Get common element between two matrices and assign rest NA. I tried following code but couldn't get a solution

Tags: r

I would like to get common elements between two matrices and assign NA for rest.

```
    m <- matrix(seq(1:28), byrow = T, ncol =7)
    colnames(m) <- paste0("V", 1:7)
    n <- matrix(seq(1:154), byrow = T, ncol = 7)
    colnames(n) <- paste0("V", 1:7)
    k <- matrix(seq(1:28), byrow =T, ncol = 7)
    colnames(k) <- paste0("V", 1:7)
    nk <- rbind(n,k)

    for(i in 1:dim(nk)[1]){
        for(j in 1:dim(nk)[2])
        if(nk[i,j] != nk[match(as.matrix(m), nk)]){
         nk[i,j] <- NA
       } else(nk)
     }
```

I would like to get something like this##

---

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
    1   2  3  4  5  6  7 
    8   9 10 11 12 13 14
    15 16 17 18 19 20 21
    22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    1   2  3  4  5  6  7 
    8   9 10 11 12 13 14
    .
    22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

The error message I got is: 
   In if (nk[i, j] != nk[match(as.matrix(m), nk)]) { ... :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Maybe `res <- nk; res[!(nk %in% m)] <- NA; res`?

Comment: This could also be written  `replace(nk, ! nk %in% m, NA)` without overwriting `nk`.

Comment: Thanks both codes worked pretty well!